# Upload Large Video Files to Website > 5mb

Tags: asp.net, .net, file-upload, video-streaming, large-files

Need some proven advice / techniques...

Think, youtube...

We are struggling with uploading large video files through ASP. Have tried Ajax, normal post file upload, all the different techniques for timeouts etc, but just cant get a good solution going...

Are there any 3rd party controls that can do the job in a consistent error free manner? We keep on battling with browser timeouts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General technique would involve splitting the file into chunks, saved in temporary directory and then merge them when upload is complete. For commercial solution you can check Telerik's [RadAsyncUpload](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload.aspx) Component.